# In Aaronson's Shor's algorithm sealed room analogy, what happens if I wake up only every 48 hours?

Tags: shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

I've been reading Aronson's [blog post about Shor's algorithm](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=208). In his sealed room analogy, what happens if I wake up only every 48 hours? Won't this procedure wrongly indicate that I'm on a 24-hour wake-up schedule? If so, is there additional work in the algorithm to compensate for that?